# Non-Circular Ellipse Nomenclature

Tags: geometry

A circle a special case of an ellipse. Is there a general word to describe an ellipse that is specifically *not* a circle?

Comment: An oblong ellipse perhaps?

Comment: Not AFAIK, like there is no word for a non-square rectangle. "Eccentric ellipse" conveys the idea but chances are low that this is self-explanatory enough.

Comment: After a little Web search, "oblong" is probably a good qualifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oval would be one possibility, since it typically indicates a non-circular shape. All ovals are not ellipses, however.

Comment: But "oval ellipse" could do.